# What should I do with this bare spot on the step?

Tags: wood, patch

The bare spot you see below used to be covered by a gnarly patch of carpet, but I removed it when I laid that tile down.  My intent was to put the same tile design over that spot, but I never got around to it.  I am still considering it, but I am wondering what you guys recommend as far as overall aesthetics are concerned.  I am mainly interested in hiding that ugly wood that has been exposed for over two years, but am not sure of the best way to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick a piece of wood on it. Either stain to match the wood rising up the stairs or paint it white to match the skirting boards.